# Sequencejs, jump to slide in sequence

Tags: slider, parallax

I'm trying to use [sequencejs](http://www.sequencejs.com/) for my horizontal parallax slider. I used this because I need a slider with custom pagination (on the bottom page).

I have a problem when the I manually jump from the 1st slide to the 3rd slide, the 2nd slide doesn't have the "animate-out" class, so the animation in 2nd will start from right side.

Is it possible to make the slide jump in sequence, like when I jump to the 3rd, I have to play the 2nd slide first? So the animation will play in sequence like parallax scrolling.

example site : http://muncul.in/test/themes/sample/

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. Answered in further detail [here](https://github.com/IanLunn/Sequence/issues/272).